# Python add item to dictionary value that is a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary called groups.  It looks like this:  `groups = {'yellow': {}}`.  How do I add input names to the 'yellow' key?
My code asks for a player's name: `name = input("player's name")`.  If a player's name is John, how do I take that inputted value and store it like this: `groups = {'yellow': {'john': []}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you try to set a value to a key that doesn't exist in the dictionary, it will add that to the dictionary

eg: `dict[newKey] = someValue` will add `newKey` with `someValue` to `dict`

If the key already exists it will update the value

```
groups = {'yellow': {}}
name = input("player's name")
groups['yellow'][name]=[]
print(groups)
```

```
player's nameJohn
{'yellow': {'John': []}}
```